# Tensorflow installation error

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow with virtualenv
I have successfully went through the first 5 steps but on the 5th

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I am getting an error

```
Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Z5MKQS-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be installing globally try adding sudo

```
sudo pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Otherwise just upgrade numpy separately with sudo and then you can try to install tensorflow locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you have that error.
But you can try with first installing pip3 and then try install with pip3 as
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
This will help you.